# Abstracting access to Entity-Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

I have an entity in EF called Registry that I use for throwing all kinds of useful stuff in.  My typical query looks like this:

```
db.Registry
   .Where(x => x.Domain == "SomeDomain" && x.Key == "SomeKey")
   .Select(x => x.Value)
   .Single();
```

where `db` is a variable of type `EFContainer`.  Rather than having this sort of query all over the place I'd like to write something much simpler, perhaps like:

```
Registry.Get(Key: "SomeKey", Domain: "SomeDomain")
```

but the problem is that in order for that method to access the database it needs to instantiate `EFContainer` and when it does, I start to have errors that IEntity change tracker cannot handle the second connection.  I suppose I could pass in my `db` variable to the method but that's eeky.

What's a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical way to do this would be to create a RegisterRepository and inject either the EFContainer into the constructor of the repository or inject a mechanism for creating containers.

```
public class RegistryRepository {
public RegistryRepository(EFContainer db) {
  this.db = db;
}

readonly EFContainer db;

public Registry Get(string domain, string key) {
// implementation here
}

}
```

In this implementation you have to consider how you will obtain a reference to the repository and thus how the repository will be constructed. You may use a [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) framework to register the EF container and the repository with a proper lifetime scope. If for example you are developing an ASP.NET application, an EF context would be scoped by an HTTP request as would the repository.

Comment: so there's no getting around having to pass in the container.  sigh... but thanks for the link on dependency injections! (something new for me to read about)

Comment: incidentally, I found out that there really is no problem instantiating the container twice, as long as you don't mix them i.e. object-from-container-1.property = object-from-container-2